# Trouble creating for loop with multiple commands to read csv files

Tags: text-processing, awk, sort, csv

I'm trying to create a for loop that reads prints the file name, alphabetizes fields, and  adds html tags that would ultimately create an html file that looks like

```
<h3 id= filename> file </h3>

<li> field2(field3)</li>
<li> field2(field3)</li>
<li> field2(field3)</li>...

<h3 id= filename> file </h3>
```

and so on.

So far I have this:

```
     for file in *.csv; do
         awk 'FNR == 1{ print "<h3 id=" file ">" file "</h3>" }' | sort -t"," -k2 | awk -F "," '{print "<li>" $2 "(" $3 ")<\li>" }' > *.html 
     done
```

The last two commands work well together, but the first one messes them all up and I end up getting an empty html file. I'm also unsure if I'm even creating the right for loop for this situation.

Comment: Focus on getting the first awk script to work, THEN iteratively add pipes and a loop. Any time you have a problem with a shell script, copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net first. [edit] your question to contain concise, testable sample input and expected output if you still have a question after fixing what shellcheck tells you about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have (reformatted slightly for readability):

```
for file in *.csv; do
  awk 'FNR == 1{ print "<h3 id=" file ">" file "</h3>" }' |
    sort -t"," -k2 |
    awk -F "," '{print "<li>" $2 "(" $3 ")<\li>" }' > *.html 
done
```

1. That first `awk` command doesn't make any sense. It is neither receiving any input on *stdin* nor is it receiving a list of files as arguments: in other words, it's not processing anything.

   → We need to provide input to awk, either like this:

   ```
   awk '...awk script here...' "$file"
   ```

   Or by feeding it input on *stdin*.
2. You're attempting to reference the `awk` variable `file`. but there is no such variable. There is of course a *shell* variable by that name, but `awk` doesn't know anything about it.

   → We need to feed the `file` variable to `awk`. We can do something like:

   ```
   awk -v file="$file" ...
   ```
3. The way you've attempted to insert a `sort` *between* two `awk` calls seems awkward.

   → Let's call `sort` first and then feed the output to `awk`
4. You're never creating the `<ul>...</ul>` around your list elements.

   → Let's make sure to include those elements in our output.
5. You're trying to redirect the output to `*.html`, but that's not going to do what you want. That will produce different behavior depending on what files exist in the current directory.

   → We should construct the output filename based on the input filename. If for an input file named `something.csv` we want to output to `something.html`, we can write:

   ```
   "${file%.csv}.html"
   ```

   The expression `${file%.csv}` is a bash expression that strips the `.csv` from the contents of the `file` variable.

It looks like maybe you want something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.csv; do
  sort -t"," -k2 "$file" |
  awk -v file="$file" -F"," '
    BEGIN {
      printf "<h3 id=\"%s\">%s</h3>\n", file, file
      printf "<ul>\n"
    }
    {
        printf "<li>%s (%s)</li>\n", $2, $3
    }
    END {
      printf "</ul>\n"
    }
  ' > "${file%.csv}.html"
done
```

Given the input:

```
alice,8,alice,alice,alice
bob,6,bob,bob,bob
carol,7,carol,carol,carol
david,5,david,david,david
edith,4,edith,edith,edith
frank,3,frank,frank,frank
grace,2,grace,grace,grace
```

This produces as output:

```
<h3 id="file1.csv">file1.csv</h3>
<ul>
<li>2 (grace)</li>
<li>3 (frank)</li>
<li>4 (edith)</li>
<li>5 (david)</li>
<li>6 (bob)</li>
<li>7 (carol)</li>
<li>8 (alice)</li>
</ul>
```

(You could replace my use of `printf` in the awk script with `print`, but I find `printf` easier to work with.)

Comment: If you put a space between `-v` and `file=` in `-vfile` then it'll behave the same way in any awk, it won't require GNU awk.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for answering this question! It was incredibly helpful. How can I compile all these files into one in the loop? I tried to do it but Sublime took 10 minutes to open lol. I don' know what I did wrong